# Python flask web application won't get user inputs

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am looking to process a python script through the clicking of an HTML link on my webpage. Here is the Javascript I have so far to handle the click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var submit_form = function(e) {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
                a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
                b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
            }, function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data.result);
                $('input[name=a]').focus().select();
            });
            return false;
        };
        $('a#calculate').bind('click', submit_form);

        $('input[name=a]').focus();
    });
</script>
```

And below is the python script I have, which uses Flask get the appropriate user inputs:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080))
    host = os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0')
    app.run(port=port, host=host)
```

The HTML code doesn't like the line `var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }},` as it returns an error on the curly brackets. When I replace it with the root URL of my application, I can't seem to get my webpage to actually update with the results of the python script. Any suggestions?

I am using cloud 9 as my IDE, which hosts with Apache. I am very new to both Javascript and Flask, and am really looking to get this basic app down so I can keep learning!

Comment: So you are telling `{{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};` this cause the issue ?

Comment: Is your JavaScript code inside a JavaScript file or a Jinja template? Files inside static are served as-is. You'd need to define `$SCRIPT_ROOT` inside a template.

Answer (score 0):

However it should work, but for simplicity you could simply remove it at all, flask will resolve it as a relative path. change your index.html and it will work.

HINT: keep sure to put your index.html under "templates" directory and run it in your terminal or command prompt "python site.py"

```
main_dir
    |--site.py
    |--templates
             |--index.html
```

index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var submit_form = function(e) {
            $.getJSON('/_add_numbers', {
                a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
                b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
            }, function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data.result);
                $('input[name=a]').focus().select();
            });
            return false;
        };
        $('a#calculate').bind('click', submit_form);

        $('input[name=a]').focus();
    });
</script>
<input name="a" />
<input name="b" />
<a href="#" id="calculate">calculate</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```